# I'm trying to make a program which rotated the matrix clockwise, and I think there's some problem with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int mat[3][3]={
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
    int nmat[3][3];
    int *s=mat[0][0];
    int *t=nmat[0][2];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        *t=*s;
        s++; t=t+3;
    }
    int *q=mat[2][0];
    int *w=nmat[0][0];
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        *w=*q;
        q++; w=w+3;
    }
    int *a=mat[2][0];
    int *b=nmat[0][0];
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        *b=*a;
        a=a-3; b++;
    }
    int *x=mat[2][2];
    int *y=nmat[2][0];
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        *b=*a;
        a=a-3; b++;
    }
    int *p=nmat[0][0];
    int j;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (j=0; j<3; j++){
            printf("%d ", *p);
            p++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in c and I was practicing some questions.
I am trying to make a program that rotates a matrix clockwise, but it does not seem to work. where is my code wrong?

[image: The program doesn't print anything]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *s=mat[0][0];` Here you declare `s` as a `pointer of type int`, while you initialize it with `mat[0][0]`, which is of type `int`.